# Is figure figcaption appropriate for image galleries?

Tags: html, image, w3c, figure

Can I use figure element like this:

```
<ul>

  <li>
    <figure>
      <a href="url"> <img src="url"> </a>

      <figcaption>
        <div>
          <p> yo this is my naked wife check out more pix <a href="url"> here </a> </p>
        </div>
      </figcaption>

    </figure>
  </li>

  <li>
    etc.
```

?

Comment: Seems like a lot of mark-up for very little gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible use of the [`figure` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element), yes.

(Note that your `img` needs an `alt` attribute. And you might want to omit the `div`, as you could target the `figcaption` or `p` directly.)